# Dates from Task Form show US format unless date does not exist

Tags: excel, vba

I have a small user interface, using Excel's Form functionality, which allows users to input start and finish dates for projects.

If the user puts in dates that are available in both the US and UK formats (e.g. 7th May 2018, 5/7/2018) the variable will come out in the US format (e.g. 5th July 2018, 5/7/2018). However, if the dates are not available in both formats (e.g. 31st August 2018, 31/8/2018), the variable will return in the (correct) UK format.

My current code for the particular variables in the form is as follows:

```
Private Sub Calculate_Click()

    sDate = CDate(sDate.Text)
    eDate = CDate(eDate.Text)

    If sDate = vbNullString Then
        sDate = Now()
    End If

    If eDate = vbNullString Then
        eDate = Now() + 40
    End If

    If HoursPD = vbNullString Then
        HoursPD = 6
    ElseIf HoursPD > 7.5 Then
        HoursPD = 7.5
    End If

    Me.Hide

End Sub
```

Is there any way to ensure that the variable format is fixed to the UK version?

Comment: Don't use `String` variables, use `Date` variables.

Comment: If sDate is blank then `sDate = CDate(sDate.Text)` will fail as a Null value can't be coerced into a date.

Comment: Are your windows regional short date settings DMY (UK) or MDY (US)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd use a separate procedure to check any dates on the form.
This also colours the control red if a non-valid date is entered.
Formatting the date as `dd-mmm-yyyy` makes it easier to spot a date in the wrong format as month is written in full(ish).

```
Public Sub FormatDate(ctrl As Control)

    Dim dDate As Date
    Dim IsDate As Boolean

    On Error GoTo ERR_HANDLE

    If Replace(ctrl.Value, " ", "") <> "" Then
        On Error Resume Next
            dDate = CDate(ctrl.Value)
            IsDate = (Err.Number = 0)
            On Error GoTo 0
        On Error GoTo ERR_HANDLE

        If IsDate Then
            ctrl.Value = Format(ctrl.Value, "dd-mmm-yyyy")
            ctrl.BackColor = RGB(255, 255, 255)
        Else
            ctrl.BackColor = RGB(255, 0, 0)
        End If
    End If

EXIT_PROC:
        On Error GoTo 0
        Exit Sub

ERR_HANDLE:
        'Error Handling routines.
        'DisplayError Err.Number, Err.Description, "mdl_FormatDate.FormatDate()"
        Resume EXIT_PROC

End Sub
```

This is then called on the `AfterUpdate` event of the control:

```
Private Sub txtDate_AfterUpdate()

    On Error GoTo ERR_HANDLE

    With Me
        FormatDate .txtDate
    End With

EXIT_PROC:
        On Error GoTo 0
        Exit Sub

ERR_HANDLE:
        'Error Handling routines.
        'DisplayError Err.Number, Err.Description, "Data_Entry_Form.txtDate_AfterUpdate()"
        Resume EXIT_PROC

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like below, but your users should know to enter the dates in the correct (UK) format:

```
    sDate = Format(CDate(sDate.Text), "dd/mm/yyyy")
    EDate = Format(CDate(EDate.Text), "dd/mm/yyyy")
```